# How can I determine a pressed button in certain time window and do one action?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an enemy which does an attack. If the player hasn't pressed a button to defend himself at that moment, he will receive damage for this attack. So far I'm checking in Update if any attack animation is playing and start a Coroutine.

```cs
{
    if ( enemy.CheckIfAnimationIsPlaying ( "Enemy_mainAttack" ) || 
        enemy.CheckIfAnimationIsPlaying ( "Enemy_mainAttack2" ) || 
        enemy.CheckIfAnimationIsPlaying ( "Enemy_firstAttack" ) )
    {
        StartCoroutine ( DefendTiming ( ) );
    }
}

private IEnumerator DefendTiming ( )
{
    float animationLength = enemy.animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds ( animationLength );

    if ( !defendButtonPressed && !receivedDamage )
    {
        ReceiveDamage ( enemy.attack );
        receivedDamage = true;
    }
    else
    {
        this.ReduceEndurance ( false, 3 );
        defendButtonPressed = true;
    }
}
```

But this approach doesn't work properly and looks not suitable. Thanks for help :)

Comment: I would do it all differently. So i would have the enemy just answer is fighting, which is set when that animation starts and is set to false on end.  Then. In update. If enemy fighting and key down then enemy.attack defended = true.   As the animation ends and attacking false an event would fire call player damage if necessary or whatever but also set everything to false again ready for next attack

Comment: Thank you! Setting a bool enemyIsFighting connected with animation is a good idea. I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

Add EventTrigger component to your button and use its functions like PointerDown and PointerUp for setting your bool(s).

[image: EventTrigger Component]

Comment: I was thinking about this but in this case the player can just hold the button pressed to keep a bool state, no?

Comment: You can set time limit on pressed state.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the started coroutine in a `Coroutine` and stop it when the button is pressed. Something like that:

```
private Coroutine _defTimingCoroutine;

private void OnEnemyAttack()
{
    ...
    _defTimingCoroutine = StartCoroutine(DefendTiming);
}

private void OnButtonClick()
{
    StopCoroutine(DefendTiming);
    // other things like stop animation, etc.
}
```